# Rearranging longitudinal data

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that is roughly structured like this:

```
case Year      2001 2002 2003 2004
1    2003      0    0    0    3
2    2002      0    5    3    2
3    2001      3    3    2    2
```

I am trying to restructure it so that every column represents the first, second (etc.) year counting from the "Year" variable, i.e.:

```
case Year      yr1  yr2  yr3 yr4
1    2003      0    3    0    0 
2    2002      5    3    2    0
3    2001      3    3    2    2
```

This code downloads the dataset and tries the solution suggested by @akrun, but it fails.

```
library("devtools")
df1 <- source_gist("b4c44aa67bfbcd6b72b9")

df1[-(1:2)] <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {x <- df1[i, ]; x1 <- unlist(x[-(1:2)]); indx <- which(!is.na(x1))[1]; i <- as.numeric(names(indx))-x[,2]+1; x2 <- x1[!is.na(x1)]; x3 <- rep(NA, length(x1)); x3[i:(i+length(x2)-1)]<- x2; x3}))
```

This generates:

```
Error in i:(i + length(x2) - 1) : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(1:234[[1L]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

How can I transform the data so that every column represents the first, second (etc.) year counting from the value in  the "Year" variable for each row?

Comment: I was only looking at the expected output.  sorry, I may have missed that key attribute.

Comment: For the first row, `3` got rearranged to `yr2`.  I am not getting the connection here.

Comment: Because the yr1=2003 as specified in the "Year" variable

Comment: @akrun - are you writing a new solution? The solution you had certain value - with manual editing of the dataset it could work...

Comment: I still didn't get the connection after staring at your expected and input data

Comment: For case 1 the Year variable is 2003, so yr1=2003, but there is no value for 2003 so it should be blank, the first value occurs in 2004, which then should be yr2.

Comment: Try this `df1[-(1:2)] <-  do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {x <- df1[i, ]; x1 <- unlist(x[-(1:2)]); indx <- which(!is.na(x1))[1]; i <- as.numeric(names(indx))-x[,2]+1; x2 <- x1[!is.na(x1)]; x3 <- rep(NA, length(x1)); x3[i:(i+length(x2)-1)]<- x2; x3}))` and change the column names

Comment: Could you try the above solution and check if that works?

Comment: Is this for the 3 columns? I think a sufficient solution need to be based on the dataset, try `library(RCurl)`
`x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/bfca2bd1ee84ce701f0c/raw/c37f7f935240d5f2f67b26d2d838f47f2a612782/longitudinal_dataset.csv")`
`y <- read.csv(text = x)`

Comment: I didn't test it on your original dataset.  Also, didn't specify 3 or 4 columns in the code.  So, I guess it should work.

Comment: I get some error using the code `y <- read.csv(text = x)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71915/discussion-between-histelheim-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should create the manipulation you are looking for.

```
library("devtools")
df1 <- source_gist("b4c44aa67bfbcd6b72b9")
temp <- df1[[1]]

library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(stringi) 

temp <- temp %>% 
  gather(new.Years, X, -Year) %>%  # convert rows to one column
  mutate(Year.temp=paste0(rownames(temp), "-", Year)) %>% # concatenate the Year with row number to make them unique
  mutate(new.Years = as.numeric(gsub("X", "", new.Years)), diff = new.Years-Year+1) %>% # calculate the difference to get the yr0 yr1 and so on
  mutate(diff=paste0("yr", stri_sub(paste0("0", (ifelse(diff>0, diff, 0))), -2, -1))) %>% # convert the differences in Yr01 ...
  select(-new.Years) %>% filter(diff != "yr00") %>% # drop new.Years column
  spread(diff, X) %>%  # convert column to rows
  select(-Year.temp) # Drop Year.temp column

temp[is.na(temp)] <- 0 # replace NA with 0

temp %>% View
```

Notice that this will work for up to 99 years.

Comment: your assumption about simplifying the data distorts it. Each case is unique, even though some cases have the same value for the "Year" variable (and potentially also other variables too, such as counts in different years).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibilty:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("case", "Year")) %>%
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(as.character(variable)),
         yr = variable - Year + 1) %>%
  filter(variable >= Year) %>%
  dcast(case + Year ~ yr, fill = 0)

#   case Year 1 2 3 4
# 1    1 2003 0 3 0 0
# 2    2 2002 5 3 2 0
# 3    3 2001 3 3 2 2
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(case = 1:3, Year = c(2003L, 2002L, 2001L), `2001` = c(0L, 
0L, 3L), `2002` = c(0L, 5L, 3L), `2003` = c(0L, 3L, 2L), `2004` = c(3L, 
2L, 2L)), .Names = c("case", "Year", "2001", "2002", "2003", 
"2004"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I can't get this to work on the real data: `library(devtools)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df <- source_gist("b4c44aa67bfbcd6b72b9")
start <- 1
case <- seq(start, 234, 1)
df1 <- cbind(case, df)

df1 %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("case", "Year")) %>%
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(as.character(variable)),
         yr = variable - Year + 1) %>%
  filter(variable >= Year) %>%
  dcast(case + Year ~ yr, fill = 0)` this returns `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'variable' not found` - what is variable supposed to be here?

Comment: @histelheim Your third line should be `df <- source_gist("b4c44aa67bfbcd6b72b9")$value`.

Comment: @Henrik I think you should use `gsub('X','',variable)` rather than `as.character(variable)` to substitute the `X` at the start of each variable.

Comment: @nograpes Thanks for your comment. I used the data set provided by OP, and there is no `X` in the start of the variable name (I have added `dput` of data frame).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
dt.m = melt(dt, id = 1:2, variable.factor = FALSE)
dt.m[, variable := as.integer(variable)-Year+1L]
dcast.data.table(dt.m, case + Year ~ variable, fill=0L, 
      value.var = "value", subset = (variable > 0L))
#    case Year 1 2 3 4
# 1:    1 2003 0 3 0 0
# 2:    2 2002 5 3 2 0
# 3:    3 2001 3 3 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library("devtools")
df1 <- source_gist("b4c44aa67bfbcd6b72b9")$value
```

I have an X in the colnames and remove it:

```
colnames(df1) <- gsub("X", "", colnames(df1))
```

I have got a solution without any additional packages:

```
startYear <- as.numeric(colnames(df1)[2])
shifts <- df1$Year - startYear
n <- ncol(df1)

df2 <- df1
colnames(df2)[-1] <- 1:(n-1) 
df2[,2:n]  <- NA

for(row in 1:nrow(df1)){
    if(shifts[row]>=0){
        df2[row,2:(n-shifts[row])] <- df1[row, (shifts[row]+2):n]
        #df2[row,2:(n-shifts[row])] <- colnames(df1)[(shifts[row]+2):n]
    }else{
        df2[row, (-shifts[row]+2):n] <- df1[row, 2:(n+shifts[row])]
        #df2[row, (-shifts[row]+2):n] <- colnames(df1)[2:(n+shifts[row])]
    }
}
```

You can prefill  `df2` with `0` instead of `NA` of corse. Decomment second rows and comment first rows in the ifelse condition to validate the permutation.

Hope it does what you wanted.

Comment: this produces *both* NA and 0? What's the difference?

Comment: I didn't want to produce data where previously no data have been. NA means "not available" and is used in R wherever there are no data. But you simply can alter the command in line 7 to ```df2[,2:n]  <- 0``` and you get only 0.